# Visual composer backend editor not working with U-design theme older versions

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, visual-composer

So I had this issue for quite a long time on my client's website which was running u-design theme version `2.12.3`. The backend editor, screen options, or any other drop down was not working. There were multiple JS errors in the console and whole website was messed up. I have finally found a solution after a month of brain storming. Posting this as a solution to help whoever encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install two plugins: 
-[Classic editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)
-[CMB2 Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/)

Now navigate to your theme folder and edit the file `wp-content/themes/u-design/lib/u-design-cmb2/u-design-cmb2-functions.php`, Comment out this on line 37:

```
//add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'udesign_cmb2_metaboxes' );
```

and on line 57, set the value of property `closed` for `$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(` as `true`:

```
    $cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'            => 'udesign_metabox',
    'title'         => __( 'U-Design Options', 'udesign' ),
    'object_types'  => array( 'post', 'page', 'essential_grid'), // Post type
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
    'closed'        => true, // Keep the metabox closed by default
) );
```

Cheers! your backend editor is now working. The fix works because there is error in theme's settings box which gets stuck on loading on the edit page, which does not allow other JS files to load and function too, blocking all editor and other wordpress scripts. So we disable the initialization of that setting box. Plus installing those plugins helps fix other errors which prevent backend editor from working especially on newer wordpress version 5.0.1 and above.

If it helps anyone in the future drop a like :)